# Pydantic Map values over a default list

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I got a base model that exist of some variables and a list.

The list exist of objects related to time.
The data that is retrieved has optionally all 24 hours.
But in some cases there isn't data on some hour and this field will then not exist.

I want to create a default list with 24 objects.

Then I would like to update the data of the list based on the hour value it retrieves from the server. If there isn't a hour I would like keep the field.

Current situation
(Note that 4 is missing as there is no data from the api)

```
[
object {hour:1, data:"something"},
object {hour:2, data:"something"},
object {hour:3, data:"something"},
object {hour:5, data:"something"},
.... to 24
]
```

What I want

```
[
object {hour:1, data:"something"},
object {hour:2, data:"something"},
object {hour:4, data: "something"},
object {hour:4, data: None},
object {hour:5, data: "something"},
.... to 24
]
```

I want to aproach this by overwritting the **init** function.
But are there other, better solutions?

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: This isn't a question about a tutorial it's more that pydantic doesn't specify how to handle this specific behaviour and i'm looking for a best practice. I could fix this by editing the init function as I already told. But maybe there are better solutions

Comment: It seems to me this question would be better ask in another forum possibly [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  You'll need to show real code in context, not a minimal example program; be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Comment: Oke thanks for the suggestion will try it somewhere else

Comment: You can use pydantic's validators for the field: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/

Comment: @MatsLindh I fixed it by overwritting the init and pass all the data to a premade list that is created in the init and then map the data over the list. That seemed to be the simpellest solution.